# Relationship between angle of vectors and orthogonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, angle, orthonormal

I'm trying to understand the following question:

Let $u_1,...,u_d$ be a set of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $a,b$ be unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\angle(a,b) < \epsilon$. If we orthogonalize $a$ and $b$ with respect to the $u_i's$ (with some Holder Transformation / Gram-Schmidt for both vectors) to $v_a,v_b$, is there a bound to $\angle(v_a,v_b)$ related to $\epsilon$? It seems like the angles should basically be the same, but I can't prove it nor can I find a good reference about what this bound should be, even if not $\epsilon$.

EDIT: To give some context: The main question I'm looking to show that there are orthonormal bases $<u_1,...,u_d,v_a>$ and $<u_1,...,u_d,v_b>$ for the spaces spanned by $<u_1,...,u_d,a>, <u_1,...,u_d,b>$ respectively, such that $\angle(v_a,v_b) < \epsilon$ or some function of $\epsilon$, given that $u_1,...,u_d$ are orthonormal and $a,b$ are unit vectors with $\angle(a,b)<\epsilon$. I see why Gram-Schmidt may not work given Eric's example in the comments, but is there an answer to this question?

ADDITIONAL EDIT: We assume the the subspaces mentioned in the above edit are not the same.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you mean unit vectors? If not, what do you mean by normal?

Comment: Yes, unit vectors

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonalize $a$ and $b$ with respect to the $u_i's$"?

Comment: Possibly useful example:  Let $n = 2$, $d = 1$, $u_1 = (1,0)$, $a = (100,1)$, and $b = (100,-1)$.

Comment: Work through some numerical examples in 2D or 3D. Draw some pictures. Consider the geometry.

Comment: @copper.hat Here's the context: I have two subspaces spanned by d+1 vectors $<u_1,,,u_d, a> and <u_1,...,u_d,b>$ where $a,b$ are unit vectors, $u_1,...,u_d$ are orthonormal and $\angle (a,b) <\epsilon$, and I want to come up with an orthonormal basis for the spaces where the d+1th basis vectors for each space are reasonably close together (i.e. their angle is some function on $\epsilon$). So I thought I could orthogonalize $a,b$ by Gram Shmidt (i.e taking $a - \Sigma$ proj$_{u_i}(a)$ and normalizing or something of the sort.)

Comment: @EricTowers I added some context to the problem, in case that clarifies things.

Comment: Doesn't appear to change my example.  Scale $a$ and $b$ by their lengths and discover $v_a$ and $v_b$ are (still) antiparallel.

Comment: I mean't more so that in those cases, there do still exist orthonormal bases $<u_1,...,u_d,v_a>, <u_1,...,u_d,v_b>$ such that span$<u_1,...,v_a> = $ span$<u_1,...,a>$ and similarly for b and $\angle(v_a,v_b) < \epsilon$. I want to show one can always find $v_a,v_b$

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer the question and add to @AlDante 's response above, while it is true that $\|v_a-v_b\|$ is small, this doesn't show that the angle between $v_a$ and $v_b$ is small. In fact, it does not have to be. if $a$ and $b$ are close together **and** very very close to any of the vectors $u_i$, then the perpendicular components $v_a,v_b$ have very small entries and the norm of their difference is small, But the could even be orthogonal (It's actually a great geometric exercise to convince yourself of why). I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spanned by $u_1,...,u_d$. Both $a$ and $b$ can be uniquely decomposed into their projections $u_a$, $u_b$ on $U$ and a vector $v_a$, $v_b$ orthogonal to $U$. As $a$ and $b$ are similar (the angle between them is small) their projections are similar.

$v_a$, $v_b$ in their turn are similar.

$\left\| a - b \right\| = \left\| (u_a + v_a) - (u_b + v_b) \right\| $
As $\left\| a - b \right\|$ is small (similar vectors) and $\left\| u_a - u_b \right\|$ is small by projection,  $\left\| v_a - v_b \right\|$ is small.

As the starting points ($u_a$ resp. $u_b)$ and endpoints ($a$ resp. $b$) are close to one another the angle between $v_a$ and $v_b$ is  therefore also small.

Comment: $v_a$ and $v_b$ are not orthogonal to one another, they are parallel to one another. If you have projected a vector onto a subspace, what is left is by definition of projection orthogonal to that subspace.

Comment: I edited that out. See the new edited comment. Either way, how is the example I gave not a counter example to your claim

Comment: Did you downvote my answer? If so, can you please explain why?

Comment: Edited comment: Why is the angle between $v_a$ and $v_b$ equal to 0? They can both be orthogonal to $<u_i>$ and not parallel to each other. E.g. Let U = span($e_1$) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $e_2$ and $e_2$ rotated by a small angle around the x axis are both orthogonal to $e_1$ but not parallel to each other

Comment: If you want any further explanation, please answer my question. Otherwise I'm moving on to a new question.

Comment: Because as I understand it, your claim is incorrect. Counterexample: $u_1 = (1,0,0)^T$. $a = (0,1,0)^T$ and $b$ is a rotation of $a$ by a small angle around the x axis. Then $u_a = u_b = 0$, $v_a = a, v_b = b$ but $v_a$ is clearly not parallel to $v_b$

Comment: I think you have found a degenerate counterexample, because the line is not a hyperplane. If I amend my answer to exclude $d=1$, would you be satisfied?

BTW: Downvoting without an explanation as to why is considered bad manners. You asked for help, and I am offering it. No need to be rude.

Comment: I added the comment before downvoting, but I'll wait for your response next time.  Apologies. Regarding the counter example, one could consider in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $u_1 = e_1, u_2 = e_2$. Then pick $a = e_3$ and b = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & cos \theta & -sin \theta \\
0 & 0 & sin \theta & cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix} $\cdot a$ (i.e some rotation again) for some small $\theta$. Wouldn't that be a counter-example? Same idea.

Comment: One could also pick $b = e_4$ now that I think about it.

Comment: I thought about $b=e_4$, but that isn't close to $e_3$. I've got a meeting and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I keep going round & round and can't quite nail it. My basic idea is that the projections are similar because $a$ and $b$ similar.  So we are left with showing that the angle between $v_a$ and $v_b$ is small. Which again must be the case, because their endpoints are close. 

We have $a \cdot b \approx 1 $ so $(u_a +v_a) \cdot (u_b +v_b) \approx 1 $ so $u_a \cdot u_b + u_a \cdot v_b + v_a \cdot u_b + v_a \cdot v_b \approx 1$. The middle two terms are zero, because they are orthogonal. The first term is approx. $\left\| u_a \right\| \left\| u_b \right\|$.

Comment: Regarding your counterexample, taking the dot product of the perpendicular components 

$ \begin{pmatrix}
      0.99 & 0.01 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    
      0.99  
    
$
i.e. similar.

Comment: I agree. I haven't been able to make it precise just yet either. The other problem is with examples such as Eric's in the above comments, where the orthogonal components could be in opposite directions in a bad enough case, which is why I chose to add the context of finding some $v_a,v_b$ not necessarily one obtained from Gram Schmidt - which is basically the idea you have as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think I got the bounds to work. I'm just trying to figure out the last step of translating a bound on $||v_a - v_b|| < \epsilon$ to a bound on the angle between $v_a$ and $v_b$. Though now that I think about it, does having this bound give a bound on the angle? It could be that the perpendicular components $v_a,v_b$ are extremely small and so the norm of their difference is just small by default, but the angle between them is large.

Comment: Yep. The answer is actually no. For $a,b$ very close to $U$, the angle between $v_a,v_b$ are too sensitive to the angle between $a,b$ and you can come up with lot's of nasty counter examples where the claim fails (I guess that's what Eric was trying to explain in their comments). Thanks for the help though!